# SQL unsure how to write where statement

Tags: sql, where-clause

I want to insert rows into the `ERROR` table for each row in the `CUSTLA` table where `PHONE` contains a space or hyphen. How would i go about writing this where statement?

Comment: Rows are inserted. They have no "natural" position. So, just insert them. Make sure they contain all the information so you can later list them in your preferred order by using an `order by` clause in the `select` command.

Comment: i have already inserted the rows. However some phone numbers contain spaces and/or hyphens. I want these fields to be added into the `ERROR` table. @cars10m

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some flavor of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is what you want you want here:

```
INSERT INTO ERROR (col1, col2, ...)
SELECT c.PHONE, ...
FROM CUSTLA c
WHERE
    c.PHONE LIKE '%-%' OR c.PH0NE LIKE '% %';
```

This would insert a new record into the `ERROR` table for every record in `CUSTLA` whose phone field has a space or hyphen.  You never revealed precisely what you want to insert, so I just gave a generic select.  Note however that you may insert any column from `ERROR` or `CUSTLA`, as well as a constant value (e.g. a string or number).

Answer (score 0):

like this type:

```
INSERT INTO ERROR (col1, col2, ...)
SELECT e1, e2, ..., c1, c2, ...
FROM TBALE
WHERE
    PHONE LIKE '%-%' OR PH0NE LIKE '% %';
```